# Is it possible to an individual developer to invite another developer to manage apps on iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

I developed an application for my friend who has an individual developer registration, I have got a simple developer registration without individual enrollment.

Is it possible to invite me at the Apple App Store to manage this application? or we need a company registration?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only **Company / Organization** accounts can add additional developers to its team. As stated under the [Enrollment Selection](https://developer.apple.com/enroll/selectEnrollmentType.php?t=cm) page, in the *Individual* account section:

> **Individual Development Only**
>
> You are the only one allowed access to program resources.

Comment: This is not entirely true with regards to *managing apps*, **it is possible** on a Individual account; see my answer…

Comment: This is inconvenient if you want to debug stuff in CloudKit Dashboard with another user account.

Comment: Also the page https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/ says that individuals can't have additional developers

Answer (score 4):

Whilst @Thecafremo's answer is true for program resources, to **manage apps** as OP stated, **you can add users to access iTunes Connect without needing a company account**.

Simply go to [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) → Manage Users → iTunes Connect User → Add New User.

[image: iTunes Connect Add New User]

Comment: Thanks, I think I will try this, I never heard about this app and I'm curious, thanks again :)

Comment: Is it possible to add someone else as a developer for the individual account?

Comment: @DinithMinura, according to https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/, NO